# Как получить в Linux текущий день недели?

Tags: linux, bash

Нашел команду дающую день недели на определенную дату `date -d 1917-11-07 +%A`, но как с ее помощью получить сегодняшний день недели?

Comment: без ключа `-d` будет сегодня

Comment: `date +%u` будет выводит цифрами день недели, где `1 - понедельник`, более подробно `date --help`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

просто не указывайте дату (и время) с помощью опции `-d дата.и.время`:

```
$ date +%A
Friday
$ LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 date +%A
Пятница
```

по умолчанию программа *date* будет использовать текущее время (сегодняшнего дня).

Comment: Не забудьте добавить, что _сегодня_ — понятие растяжимое.